# Truncated element side-by-side with non-truncated element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a container with two parts of text: Variable length part and static part.

I wish for the variable length part to be truncated (a-la `text-overflow: ellipsis`) so that the container remains at one line at all times.

Here's an image to illustrate:

[image: variable vs static]

---

Now, I know I can solve it fairly simply with `display: flex` on the container like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.variable {
  margin: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.static {
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="variable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum dolorum repudiandae in, delectus similique quos natus facilis non odit laudantium unde nostrum aperiam doloremque magni cum ipsum recusandae repellat iusto quo architecto. Ea reiciendis, natus at fuga officiis, cupiditate voluptatem in, sed quae vero est nesciunt quidem tempora, dignissimos sapiente cumque eveniet. Eaque, fugiat voluptates mollitia veniam, blanditiis aut deleniti. Nesciunt sapiente vitae aut, fugit in commodi neque hic reiciendis, et cupiditate possimus, quod quaerat ducimus ea cumque nihil praesentium. Nesciunt velit magni asperiores optio quam, provident eum earum? Illo et illum, autem ratione! Perferendis non facere, ratione quas beatae?</span>
  <span class="static">| Static Text</span>
</span>
```

However, I require IE8 support or higher. So flexbox is decidedly out.

I've tried

- `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, but that doesn't play nice with variable lengths. The only solution I've found was to set the width on the variable length text which is unacceptable.
- Playing with floats, but even there, without setting the width for the either text container, I couldn't get the behavior specified above.

Does anyone have other ideas? I'd like to avoid the "I'll assume that the static part takes ~25% so I'll give 75% to the variable width one".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with a nested CSS table, the key is set the inner table to `table-layout:fixed;`, it's required for CSS `ellipsis`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysyurxam/)**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.variable,
.static {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.variable {
  width: 100%;
}

.static {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.variable-table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.variable-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="variable">
    <span class="variable-table">
      <span class="variable-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum dolorum repudiandae in, delectus similique quos natus facilis non odit laudantium unde nostrum aperiam doloremque magni cum ipsum recusandae repellat iusto quo architecto. Ea reiciendis, natus at fuga officiis, cupiditate voluptatem in, sed quae vero est nesciunt quidem tempora, dignissimos sapiente cumque eveniet. Eaque, fugiat voluptates mollitia veniam, blanditiis aut deleniti. Nesciunt sapiente vitae aut, fugit in commodi neque hic reiciendis, et cupiditate possimus, quod quaerat ducimus ea cumque nihil praesentium. Nesciunt velit magni asperiores optio quam, provident eum earum? Illo et illum, autem ratione! Perferendis non facere, ratione quas beatae?
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
<span class="static">| Static Text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I just puked a little in my mouth. +1.

Comment: First time answering a question for a moderator, I'm very excited! Thank you for keeping the community running in order.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if the span has to be dynamic per user or not, so my solution will involve a little JS to give you the ability to hard code the width. The idea is that you can say *well, I only want the variable text to be **x** characters, so let's set it to that and let JS handle the rest*.

```js
var query = document.querySelectorAll('span.variable'); //Query to grab any spans with this name.

//Only run if there are elements(s)
if (query.length > 0) {
 var variableLabel = query[0]; //For now assuming there's one, but this could be looped instead.
 var maxLength = 45; //Max length to allow, can be modified.
    variableLabel.innerText = variableLabel.innerText.substring(0,maxLength) + "..." //Set the text, with eplipsis.
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="variable" width="25%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum dolorum repudiandae in, delectus similique quos natus facilis non odit laudantium unde nostrum aperiam doloremque magni cum ipsum recusandae repellat iusto quo architecto. Ea reiciendis, natus at fuga officiis, cupiditate voluptatem in, sed quae vero est nesciunt quidem tempora, dignissimos sapiente cumque eveniet. Eaque, fugiat voluptates mollitia veniam, blanditiis aut deleniti. Nesciunt sapiente vitae aut, fugit in commodi neque hic reiciendis, et cupiditate possimus, quod quaerat ducimus ea cumque nihil praesentium. Nesciunt velit magni asperiores optio quam, provident eum earum? Illo et illum, autem ratione! Perferendis non facere, ratione quas beatae?</span>
  <span class="static">| Static Text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The text arrives from the server, and I have no control over the container's width. I also don't see you using `maxLength` anywhere.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Well, it's an option, you're right about maxLength though, I forgot to actually use it.